# Prevent the RichTextBox's height from growing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `RichTextBox` control in my WPF application. I use it to show log messages. Here's the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid"
      Margin="20,120,20,20">
  <RichTextBox x:Name="txtLog"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
               FontSize="15"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
</Grid>
```

This code is in a `UserControl` and this `UserControl` is the content of another `Window`. In that `Window`, I have a `ScrollViewer` which shows scrollbars whenever the content is bigger than the container. Here's the code for that:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="content"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Margin="0,70,0,0">
  <Controls:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="transition"
                                        Transition="LeftTransition" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

My initial problem was that whenever the log messages were filling the `RichTextBox`, it would grow and show the scrollbars on the container. I solved it by binding the height of the `RichTextBox` to the `ActualHeight` of its parent `Grid.

All is working as expect. However, there's a slight issue remaining. If I resize the paretn Window by making it bigger and then shrink it to the previous size, the height of the `RichTextBox` won't go back to its previous value and it will show the scrollbars again.

How can I solve this?

Comment: wouldn't setting `MaxHeight` on `RichTextBox` be better?

Comment: a little bit confused, do you need the scrollbar or not, if you do, when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtLog"
             Height="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
             FontSize="15"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

to

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtLog"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             FontSize="15"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

insted of binding it to the ActualWidth give it horizontal and vertical alignment stretch